# Mouse over bottom bar using CSS

Tags: html, css

So I have this menu bar. It is an unordered list and the menu bar is seperated from the content of the page with a thin, light underline. Now I want that when someone mouse overs, a link, the column should have a thick underline (not the text).

My css looks like so:

```
.main-navbar
{
    background-color:#fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #f2f2f2;    
}

.main-navbar-item li a:hover
{

    border-bottom: 5px solid #dddddd;
}
```

This works fine and I can see the thick bottom border show up on mouse over. However, the `main-navbar` line goes down to accommodate the additional 5 pixels on mouse over and comes back up on mouse out. How can I ensure that the mouse over bottom bar does not disturb the main nav bar underline?

As always, any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you post your code here http://jsbin.com

Comment: The cheat way would be to use a margin to get back the 5px. E.g margin-bottom: -5px; [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/B4Nfx/)

Comment: @Ruddy: That works, but then the mouseover thick bar shows *under* the main navbar line, but I want it *above* the navbar line...

Comment: @open_sourse Can you get a demo up for me to see please. Be so much easier as that was just a guess.

Comment: @Ruddy and test of the guys: let me try to get it to jsfiddle

Comment: @open_sourse Something like this? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/B4Nfx/1/)

Comment: @Ruddy: Heres my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3p8xN/

Comment: Not sure why, but when I pasted the code in jsfiddle, it is working properly :| I am using bootstrap locally...not sure if that affects anything

Comment: @open_sourse I was going to say it seems to work doesn't it? It maybe the default styles affecting it.

Answer (score 0):

My Best Opinion is reduce the 5px from bottom padding

Eg - See Below CSS:

```
CSS:
.main-navbar-item li a{
padding:15px  10px;
}
.main-navbar-item li a:hover 
{
padding:15px 10px 10px 10px ;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #dddddd;
}
```